# how to sum for each value and for each stage

Tags: google-bigquery, sum

For this table, i want to make addition of the points for each team in each stage of each season with bigquery

```
saison  |stage |team_home |team_away|home_goal|away_goal| home_point| away_point|   
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2002    |  1   |France    |Bresil   |2        |1        |  3        |0          |    
2002    |  1   |Italie    |Bresil   |4        |3        |  3        |0          |    
2002    |  1   |France    |Italie   |1        |1        |  1        |1          |    
2002    |  2   |Italie    |Bresil   |3        |4        |  0        |3          | 
2002    |  2   |France    |Italie   |1        |1        |  1        |1          |    
2002    |  2   |Italie    |Bresil   |3        |4        |  0        |3          | 
2002    |  3   |France    |Italie   |1        |1        |  1        |1          |    
2003    |  1   |Italie    |Bresil   |3        |4        |  0        |3          |    
2003    |  1   |France    |Italie   |1        |2        |  0        |3          |    
2003    |  1   |Bresil    |France   |0        |1        |  0        |3          |    
2003    |  2   |France    |Italie   |1        |2        |  0        |3          |    
2003    |  2   |Bresil    |France   |0        |1        |  0        |3          |    
2003    |  2   |France    |Italie   |1        |2        |  0        |3          |    
2003    |  3   |Italie    |France   |0        |1        |  0        |3          |
```

I want this result :

```
saison  |stage |team      |team_point|   
--------------------------------------
2002    |  1   |France    |4          |    
2002    |  1   |Italie    |4          |    
2002    |  1   |Bresil    |0          |  
2002    |  2   |France    |5          |    
2002    |  2   |Italie    |5          |    
2002    |  2   |Bresil    |3          |  
2002    |  3   |France    |6          |    
2002    |  3   |Italie    |6          |    
2002    |  3   |Bresil    |3          | 
2003    |  1   |France    |3          |    
2003    |  1   |Italie    |3          |    
2003    |  1   |Bresil    |3          |  
2003    |  2   |France    |6          |    
2003    |  2   |Italie    |9          |    
2003    |  2   |Bresil    |3          |  
2003    |  3   |France    |9          |    
2003    |  3   |Italie    |9          |    
2003    |  3   |Bresil    |3          |
```

I think to make unpivot and use an aggregation but i can't do it

Comment: Define your requirement clearly, what the logic for the columns like team, team_point ?

Comment: I need to know the points for each team for each stage for each season to make a ranking @vignesh

Comment: 1. team is team_home or team_away ? how this team_point calculated ?

Comment: i don't understand, the first table show the result for game between 2 team, team home and team away, with for each the goal and them the number of point if the team win, mke equality or lose the game ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider below query:

```sql
SELECT saison, stage, p.team, SUM(SUM(p.point)) OVER (PARTITION by saison, team ORDER BY stage) team_point,
  FROM sample, UNNEST([STRUCT(team_home AS team, home_point AS point), (team_away, away_point)]) p
 GROUP BY 1, 2, 3
 ORDER BY 1, 2, 4 DESC;
```

output is slightly different from your expected one :
Thanks to @Saransh's kind explanation, output get more close to your expected output <s>except one thing</s>.

(update)

```sql
WITH team_points AS (
  SELECT saison, stage, p.team, SUM(SUM(p.point)) OVER (PARTITION by saison, team ORDER BY stage) team_point,
    FROM sample, UNNEST([STRUCT(team_home AS team, home_point AS point), (team_away, away_point)]) p
   GROUP BY 1, 2, 3
)
SELECT saison, stage, team, IFNULL(team_point, LAST_VALUE(team_point IGNORE NULLS) OVER w) AS team_point
  FROM UNNEST([2002, 2003]) saison, UNNEST([1, 2, 3]) stage, UNNEST(['France', 'Bresil', 'Italie']) team
  LEFT JOIN team_points p ON p.saison = saison AND p.stage = stage AND p.team = team
WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY saison, team ORDER BY stage)  
 ORDER BY 1, 2, 3;
```

[image]

Comment: I guess OP wants sum as cumulative sum of `(previous stages sum combined + current stage sum)`. This to be partitioned over each `saison`. Very poorly framed question nonetheless.

Comment: @Saransh,  Your guess seems to be correct.  Thanks for your kind explanation. I've updated query.

Answer (score 2):

Consider below approach

```
with temp as (
  select *, 0 goal, 0 point from
  (select distinct saison from your_table),
  (select distinct stage from your_table),
  (select distinct team from your_table, unnest([team_home, team_away]) team)
)
select distinct saison, stage, team, 
  sum(goal) over prev_stages team_goals,
  sum(point) over prev_stages team_points
from (
  select * except(col) from your_table 
  unpivot ((team, goal, point) for col in 
    ((team_home, home_goal, home_point), (team_away, away_goal, away_point))
  )
  union all select * from temp
)
window prev_stages as (
  partition by saison, team order by stage 
  range between unbounded preceding and current row
)
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If all teams have played both home and away in all stages and saisons, then you can just create a column (team_point) that sums the addition of home_point and away_point grouped by saison, stage and team_home (using team away wouldn't make a difference):

```
SELECT
  saison,
  stage,
  team_home AS team,
  SUM(home_point + away_point) AS team_point
FROM
  your_dataset.your_table
GROUP BY
  saison,
  stage,
  team
ORDER BY
  saison,
  stage,
  team_point DESC --this is how teams with most points will show up first for each saison and stage.
```

If there's a chance that any team have only played home (or away) in any stage or saison, then you could list all diferent teams first.

```
WITH
  AllTeams AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT
      team_away AS team
    FROM
      your_dataset.your_table
    UNION DISTINCT
    SELECT DISTINCT
      team_home AS team
    FROM
      your_dataset.your_table)

SELECT
  saison,
  stage,
  team,
  SUM(home_point + away_point) AS team_point
FROM
  your_dataset.your_table
LEFT JOIN
  AllTeams ON team = team_home OR team = team_away
GROUP BY
  saison,
  stage,
  team
ORDER BY
  saison,
  stage,
  team_point DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

OP the requirements of your post are not very clear, please update it to reflect the actual requirements. What I could deduce from the above output is that you require the cumulative sum for each team for each *saison* to be carry forwarded to the stage 2 and 3 respectively.

```sql
WITH
  unioned_expr AS (
  SELECT
    saison,
    stage,
    team_home AS team,
    home_goal AS goals,
    home_Point AS points
  FROM
    `project.dataset.table`
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    saison,
    stage,
    team_away AS team,
    away_goal AS goals,
    away_point AS points
  FROM
    `project.dataset.table` ),
  summed_expr AS (
  SELECT
    saison,
    stage,
    team,
    SUM(points) AS points
  FROM
    unioned_expr
  GROUP BY
    saison,
    stage,
    team
  ORDER BY
    saison,
    team,
    stage )
SELECT
  saison,
  stage,
  team,
  SUM(points) OVER(PARTITION BY team, saison ORDER BY stage ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING ) as team_point
FROM
  summed_expr
ORDER BY
  saison,
  team,
  stage
```

Output:

```
saison,stage,team,team_points
2002,1,Bresil,0
2002,2,Bresil,6
2002,1,France,4
2002,2,France,5
2002,3,France,6
2002,1,Italie,4
2002,2,Italie,5
2002,3,Italie,6
2003,1,Bresil,3
2003,2,Bresil,3
2003,1,France,3
2003,2,France,6
2003,3,France,9
2003,1,Italie,3
2003,2,Italie,9
2003,3,Italie,9
```